# Firebase: Create/Update multiple child nodes atomically

Tags: android, firebase, transactions, firebase-realtime-database

Say I have a project with a "users" node and a "pets" node. When a user gets a pet, I want to both add the pet's key to the user's "pets" node and the user id to the pet's "owner" node.

**Example:**

```
{
    "users":{
        "user1":{
            "pets":{
                "pet1":true,
                "pet3":true
            }
            ...
        }
    },
    "pets":{
        "pet1":{
            "owner":"user1",
            ...
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to make sure both updates succeed to prevent an inconsistent state.

I read about how to work with Firebase transactions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions), however when I try to create a transaction that modifies the relevant values (using dbRef.runTransaction(...)), I get this DatabaseError error:

> The transaction had too many retries

The transaction only seems to work when I call runTransaction() on the specific node I modify (for example, calling

```
dbRef.child("users").child("user1").runTransaction(...));
```

However, this does not help me because I need to reach both the relevant user and the pet.
How can I make this transaction work?

Comment: The error message means that you have too much contention on updates. The solution is usually to push the transaction lower into the tree, to reduce contention. But without seeing the problematic code, it's hard to be specific.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [Firebase Docs](http://When%20working%20with%20data%20that%20could%20be%20corrupted%20by%20concurrent%20modifications,%20such%20as%20incremental%20counters), you don't need the use of a Transaction Operation (i'll explain this later).

In order to save data in multiple nodes at **ONE PACKET**, I advise you to build a **Map<>** array in which the *Key* represents the path, and the *Value* represents, well, whatever you want to store inside.

Lets say "user1" just became the owner of "pet4", and your dbRereference is pointing on the root directory:

```
FirebaseDatabase dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Map<String, Object> update = new HashMap<>();
update.put("users/user1/pets/pet4", true);
update.put("pets/pet4/owner", "user4");
```

Later you can run the **.updateChildren(Map<,>)** and attach a listener.

```
dbRef.updateChildren(update).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful())
            Log.d("Success!");
        else
            Log.d("Failure");
    }
});
```

In this way if a failure occurrs, your database won't be changed at all.

"Transaction" is a term that Firebase gave for a different operation, which I believe was the cause of your confusion: It is used when working with data that could be corrupted by concurrent modifications, such as incremental counters. For further read, open the link attached at the beginning.

Comment: I also tried using updateChildren, but this caused another problem. Say "user1" already has a pet in his "pets" node, using updateChildren() seems to override that pet and only place the new pet there. So if for example "user1" had "pet1" in the "pets" node, and I used update.put("users/user1/pets/pet4", true), he will now only have "pet4" under "pets".

Comment: Are you sure you're pointing your key to the LAST node called "pet4"? 
updateChildren override only the value that you provide, and only inside the "deepest" node that you provide. If you're saying that the whole "pets" node is changed, I can only assume that you are mistakenly editing the node above it, which is "pets". Try to make sure you're pointing to the exact location in the update, which is "pet4". I'm using this function a lot and it works like charm :)

Comment: How big can my `Map<,>` be? For example: `Firestore` can write 500 docs at a time and I havent found a similar answer for `Firebase Realtime Database`.

Comment: [This page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits#writes)'s `Writes` section has the answer to your question: Not above 256mb. It should be kept lower though, as I believe the whole write request wraps the `Map<,>` data alongside other params (node data for e.g, auth...).