# Firebase -Kotlin How To Do Atomic/Multi-Location UpdateTo Delete a Ref(s) Using Null?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I can do an atomic/multi-location update in Swift using `NSNull()` to delete multiple refs. **How can I do the same thing in Kotlin using a null type?**

```swift
let followersRef = "followers/\(otherUserId)/\(currentUserId)"
let followingRef = "following/\(currentUserId)/\(otherUserId)"
let someOtherRef = "someNode/\(currentUserId)"

var multiLocationDict = [String: Any]()
multiLocationDict.updateValue(NSNull(), forKey: followersRef) // <- NSNull() value that deletes this entire ref
multiLocationDict.updateValue(NSNull(), forKey: followingRef) // <-NSNull() value that deletes this entire ref
multiLocationDict.updateValue(1, forKey: someOtherRef) // <- Actual Value that updates or creates another ref

let rootRef = Database().database().reference()
rootRef.updateChildValues(multiLocationDict, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
    // ...
})
```

Just for a little more clarity in Swift the dictionaries can accept NSNull(). So this works in Swift to delete a ref/path using NSNull(). [See an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38466959/4833705)

```
let pathToDelete = "/someRef/\(uid)/someValue"

var dict = [String:Any]()
dict.updateValue(NSNull(), forKey: pathToDelete)

firebaseRootRef.updateChildValues(dict)
```

But this doesn't work in Kotlin

```
val pathToDelete = "/someRef/$uid/someValue"

var map = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
map[pathToDelete] = null

firebaseRootRef.updateChildren(map)
```

Comment: @Tenfour04 `atomic` meaning update multiple nodes at once. See here https://firebase.blog/posts/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56203185/4833705, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42035660/4833705

Comment: @Tenfour04 I do the Firebase atomic ref updates using NSNull() it in Swift, it definitely works. Here are some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38466959/4833705, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49042980/4833705. The problem that I'm running into here is I'm not a native Kotlin dev, I'm just learning it and also learning to use it with Firebase

Comment: @Tenfour04 You see in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38466959/4833705 it says `... is now an NSNull() object (not nil), and Firebase knows that NSNull is a nil value.`. I don't see Kotlin's version of NSNull(). I should've added an example but when I tried to add `null` to a `mutableMapOf` or `HashMap` it wouldn't let me. Example `var map = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()` ; `map[followersRef] = null`. I asked the question specifically about Firebase and maps because of what worked in Swift.

Comment: Oh, wait. You're using `NSNull` to clear some values, not to do some hack to achieve an atomic update, is that it? You just want to know how to clear values during an `updateChildValues` operation in Kotlin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253500/discussion-between-lance-samaria-and-tenfour04).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what do you mean by "atomically update", because I do not see in your code any type of synchronization.

But you can use `null` value for variables in Kotlin which declared by type marked with `?`. For instance, `Any?` type for your example and after that put null in a dictionary which holds `Any?` as value. Something like that:

```
val followersRef = "followers/$otherUserId/$currentUserId"
val followingRef = "following/$currentUserId/$otherUserId"
val someOtherRef = "someNode/$currentUserId"

val multiLocationMap = mapOf(
    followersRef to null,
    followingRef to null,
    someOtherRef to 1
)

// Then work with database
```

Comment: `atomic` meaning update multiple nodes at once. See here https://firebase.blog/posts/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56203185/4833705, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42035660/4833705

Comment: this doesn't work. I tried it and firebase wouldn't accept it as in `rootRef.updateChildren(multiLocationMap)`. It was a mismatch error. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Can you clarify "mismatch error"? Are you getting a compile time error or runtime error? Based on the documentation for the `updateChilren` function, it looks like this *should* work. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#updateChildren(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,java.lang.Object%3E)

Comment: @Tenfour04 It was a compile error. I stepped out for a sec, I'll message you and let you know the error once I come back.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I just tried it out, his answer worked. I had a compile error earlier, not sure what happened but it's working now. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @MikhailGuliaev I must've did something wrong earlier, so please ignore my earlier comment because it's working fine now. Thanks for your answer :)